# generate QT resource file using Bazel

Tags: c++, qt, bazel

I'm trying to create a Qt resource file using Bazel. I've create a macro that receives a list of files and calls Qt `rcc` function to generate the corresponding cpp file. In order to to that, I need first to generate the qrc file (xml) with the corresponding list - so I created a python binary that does exactly that (`generate_qrc`).
I currently facing couple of question:

1. is this the best way to do that? Google didn't yield any useful use case yet I'm quite sure I'm not the first one
2. For some reason the python executable is not found, do I need to define it other than adding it in `tools`? I've tried adding `$(location ...)` but I get a  `expression is not a declared prerequisite of this rule`
3. How can I run the two command (my python binary+`rcc`) one after the other? `{}`?

Thanks!

```
qt.bzl:



def qt_resource(name,file_list, **kwargs):

  native.genrule(
      name = "%s_resource" % name,
      srcs=["%s.qrc"%name]+file_list,
      outs = ["rcc_%s.cpp" % name],
      # cmd =  "rcc %s/%s.qrc -o $@"%(native.package_name(),name) ,
      cmd="generate_qrc file_list.qrc %s"%','.join(file_list),
      tools=["//third_party:generate_qrc"]
  )
  srcs = [":rcc_%s.cpp" % name]


  native.cc_library(
      name = name,
      srcs = srcs,
      hdrs = [],
      deps = [],
      **kwargs
  )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Looks like a reasonable approach to me
2. Try `$(location //third_party:generate_qrc)` in `cmd`
3. `rcc` can be run in another `genrule`, where the `outs` of the first genrule (`"%s_resource" % name`) can be put in the `srcs` of the next. It's also possible to create a `sh_binary` and a shell script that does all the work, and run that `sh_binary` in a `genrule`. Just depends on how complex things become and what feels better to you.